# Apk Security on Automatic date and time

Tags: applications, security, date-and-time

Is there any way to "mock" the Android date and time even while the option "automatic date and time" is turned on?

The reason I'm asking for such information is that my new app will have to operate offline while still being safe, thus I would need to know the "work arounds" in order to block/prevent the change of date and time even when checking for "automatic date and time" returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible on a rooted device with Xposed module [Per app hacking](http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.t2k269.perapphacking)

> Allow set a fake time to fake an app to a specific time just like time machine. Time format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI

Comment: Nice, I'll do some "reversing" on the app to see what exactly I can do to try to avoid it (I hope, I'll be able to), thank you

Comment: There may be Magisk modules too, though a quick search didn't show up. Worth checking that out as well